# Hide removable disks in Task Managers Performance tab

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

Task Manager shows all removable disks in the "Performance" tab. How can I hide them? None of them is actually plugged in. Only disk 0 and 1 are actually there.

[image]

Comment: Do you always safely eject before physically unplugging?

Comment: @harrymc I usually do, but it is possible that I forget

Comment: Try to reconnect one disk and safely eject it, to see if it's still listed.

Comment: @harrymc I did that with 2 disks, did not work

Comment: This doesn't happen on my Windows 10 - the disk disappears immediately on eject. Please run `chkdsk` on the system disk and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) for general troubleshooting.

Comment: @harrymc I did both, the disks still appear in task manager...

Comment: Did you get any warnings?

Comment: @harrymc no, both commands went smoothly

Comment: I updated to Win 10, 2004 a few days ago and I'm seeing this behavior as well. I do not remember seeing this behavior with 1909. Task manager now shows all of the empty card reader drives that come with my USB-C hub and it's really annoying because there is no (and never has been) a card in those slots.

It clutters up the view with information that is useless..

Comment: go to device manager, right click on drive you want to remove, click properties -> device tab -> disable device.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, "Hide empty drives" option in File Explorer doesn't hide those from Task Manager. For me those drives were coming from an USB memory card reader which created separate drives for each type of physical card slot on it. What I did was disable the whole USB device in Windows Device Manager by right-clicking the corresponding USB Mass Storage Device revealed by menu "View->Devices by connection" for the related drives and selecting "Disable device". Note that I tried to disable the disk drives individually but even that didn't remove those from Task Manager.